# RSpec: stub a controller method in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

View spec failing because the ApplicationController method, `logged_in?`, wants a user to be returned.

Not sure how to spec this. Currently in `before(:each)` I have:

```
controller.stub!(:logged_in?).and_return(FactoryGirl.create(:active_user))
@ballots = FactoryGirl.create_list(:full_ballot, 2)
```

which isn't working:

```
Failure/Error: render
ActionView::Template::Error:
  undefined method 'logged_in?' for #<#<Class:0x007f9c908e4b10>:0x007f9c90873b68>
```

FWIW: `:active_user` is the user factory for the user that is attached to the `:full_ballot`

**Update:** As requested:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(cookies[:id_token]) if cookies[:id_token]
  end

  def logged_in?
    current_user
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `current_user` and `logged_in?` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See how [devise test helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb) do it. It looks like you can define this method before tests and it should work:

```
def logged_in?
   FactoryGirl.create :active_user
end
```

Comment: Works great! Will leave it open for a few hours to see if there are other approaches.